# Transformation macro

Tags: r

I am writing a macro which perform following functionality

1. take a file say excel or csv
2. read all the labels
3. dynamically generate square, square-root, log  of each column with appropriate column name and write it to a new file,

I am stuck at dynamically genrateing the column names like Revenue_square etc.

Example " i have a excel with 3 columns Revenue, cost & profit

Now my Macro should be able to  read the values and for each column and perform square, square root and log of   Revenue, cost & profit and write to excel with column names as Revenue_square, Revenue_squareroot,  Revenue_log  cost_square etc...

Below is my code

```
test$Rev_square = test[c(1)]^2 
data=read.delim2("//ARLMSAN01/CTRX_Data/vikasK.sharma/Desktop/balancesheet_example.csv",header=T,sep=",") 

headings = names(data) 
show (headings) 
HEADINGS = toupper(headings) 

for ( i in 1:length(HEADINGS)) { 
  show(i) 
  data$Rev_square=data[c(i)]^2 
  show(data$Rev_square) 
  names(data) 
}
```

Comment: Check the package `XLConnect` for working with Excel sheets. That one gives you an incredible flexibility for adding columns and the likes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `paste` (or `paste0`) or `sprintf` to create the new column names, then use `[[` rather than `$` to do the assignment. Also it is better to use `seq_along` rather than `1:length` in the looping statement.

```
for(i in names(mydata)) {
  newname <- paste0(i,"_squared")
  mydata[[newname]] <- mydata[[i]]^2
}
```